# Erro ao conectar com WebService + Soap + Android

Tags: android, .net, soap

Boa tarde, estou com um problemas para me conectar ao webservice. Estou usando a biblioteca ksoap2.

```
public class CallSOAP
{
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/yteste";
    public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "yteste";
    public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.2.101/WebService.asmx";

public CallSOAP()
{
}

public String Call(EditText edtQtde)
{

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    SoapPrimitive response = null;
    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        edtQtde.setText("erro do call");
        //response = exception.toString();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

O erro ocorre em "response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();", e acaba caindo no catch() onde eu coloquei uma mensagem de erro.

Classe principal:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnAdicionar;
EditText edtQtde;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAdicionar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdicionar);
    edtQtde = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtQtde);

    final AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    btnAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            CallSOAP cs = new CallSOAP();

            try
            {
                String resp = cs.Call(edtQtde);
                ad.setMessage(resp.toString());
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ad.setMessage("erro");
            }
            ad.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Observação: a função yteste apenas retorna um string.

Obrigado

Comment: Qual o stack trace da `Exception` que é enviada para o catch?

Comment: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" . Obs: uso meu celular para testar as aplicações

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem alguns erros no seu código:

1. O erro é causado porque você está tentando fazer uma requisição HTTP na `thread` principal. Isso é um erro grave no Android.
2. Sua classe que cuida da requisição web `CallSOAP` não deveria receber uma referência para uma `View`. No caso, o `EditText` edtQtde.

Para solucionar esse problema, você precisa executar o método `Call` em uma background `thread`.

Recomendo que você dê uma olhada na documentação da classe [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ou em uma explicação de como rodar [códigos em background](http://blog.vandersonguidi.com.br/programacao-2/android/resolvendo-o-erro-networkonmainthreadexception-no-desenvolvimento-android/).

Usando o `AsyncTask`, você deve fazer o `Call` em background e atualizar suas `View`s no resultado disso:

```java
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    CallSOAP cs = new CallSOAP();
    String resp;
    try {
        resp = cs.Call();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        resp = "erro";
    }
    return resp;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    edtQtde.setText(s);
    ad.setMessage(s);
    ad.show();
}
```

Comment: Quanto a view que eu passo como parâmetro, é apenas uma gambiarra de quem tem pouco conhecimento em android, para ver onde o erro estava acontecendo. Eu pesquisei hoje pela manhã, e verifiquei que eu precisava usar threads. Resolvi meu problema com  as seguintes linhas de codigo:
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: Porém, a sua solução também é válida. Obrigado

Comment: Mudar o `StrictMode` para permitir requisições na main thread pode permitir que você execute o seu código, mas, definitivamente, não é a solução. Isso vai fazer com que você bloqueio a thread principal e pode resultar em uma péssima experiência para o usuário.

Comment: Sim Igor, pelo que vi, era a pior solução a ser implementada. Mas vai ser temporário.. Quando realmente for pra produção, vou colocar algo melhor